# In laravel 5.5 use carbon to compare 2 dates

Tags: php, laravel, datetime, php-carbon

In laravel 5.5 I use carbon to compare 2 dates, but the thing is that `createFromFormat` returns timestamp and I do not know

how to set time to `“00:00:00”` . I make :

```
echo 'passes <pre>$value::'.print_r($value, true).'</pre>';
// output 2018-08-01

$postgresql_format = config('app.postgresql_date_format', 'Y-m-d');

echo '<pre>$postgresql_format::'.print_r($postgresql_format,true).'</pre>';
// output $postgresql_format::Y-m-d

$A = preg_split("/ /", $value);
if (count($A) == 2) {
    $value= $A[0];
}

$a= Carbon::createFromFormat($postgresql_format, $value);

echo '<pre>$a->isPast()::'.print_r($a->isPast(),true).'</pre>';
//output $a->isPast():: - seems it is does not work

$today= Carbon::today();
echo '<pre>$today::'.print_r($today,true).'</pre>';
/* Output:
$today::Carbon\Carbon Object
(
    [date] => 2017-12-04 00:00:00.000000
    [timezone_type] => 3
    [timezone] => UTC
)
 */

var_dump($today->lt($a)); // bool(false)
echo '<pre>$a::'.print_r($a,true).'</pre>';

/* 
$a::Carbon\Carbon Object
(
    [date] => 2018-08-01 08:41:56.000000
    [timezone_type] => 3
    [timezone] => UTC
)
 */
```

How to set time of `$a` to `“00:00:00”` to exclude time from comparison ?

PS: `$a->isPast()` does not seems to work

Thanks!

Comment: to get "00:00:00" you can just add `->startOfDay();` to the Carbon instance : `$a->startOfDay();` !!

Answer (score 4):

If I understand correctly, you want to compare two dates based on the dates only, excluding the time.

Carbon has a method to compare it with another Carbon object, based on the date, excluding the time.

From the Carbon source code:

```
public function isSameDay(Carbon $dt)
    {
        return $this->toDateString() === $dt->toDateString();
    }
```

Where toDateString formats the date to "Y-m-d".

So you can do:

```
$date = Carbon::parse('2016-09-17 11:00:00');
$now = Carbon::now();

if ($date->isSameDay($now) ...
```

Or, in case you need to check only against today:

```
if ($date->isToday() ...
```

For more see [here](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-comparison).

Answer (score 1):

You can solve it by using like this.

`Carbon::parse('2018-08-01 08:41:56.000000')->format('Y/m/d');`

further reference is [here](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) and [here](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-getters)

For the comparison you can do it like so

```html
    $date = Carbon::parse('2016-09-17 11:00:00');
    $now = Carbon::now();

    $diff = $date->diffInDays($now);
```